# How to load the page from html code

Tags: ios, uiwebview, afnetworking

Here is the question, I use AFNetwoking get the page html returned.
And I can see the responseObject is a html page.
Here is the code I used.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.z.qq.com/moc2/authorize"];
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];


NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[params setValue:@"code" forKey:@"response_type"];
[params setValue:@"100266567" forKey:@"client_id"];
[params setValue:@"http://www.qq.com" forKey:@"redirect_uri"];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:@"https://graph.z.qq.com/moc2/authorize" parameters:params];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFHTTPRequestOperation class]];
```

__block NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] init];

```
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject){
    data = responseObject;
    NSLog(@"Response: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]) ;
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];

[operation start];
```

Now I want to load the responseObject into a uiwebview.
I tried the loadHTMLString , but it didn't work.

```
[webView loadHTMLString:[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] baseURL:url ];
```

Does anybody have any idea about this?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you are loading the data in any of the handler blocks.

AFNetworking is asynchronous.  So if you try and load the data before any has been returned, then nothing will happen.

Put the loading code in the same place that you are logging the data.

Comment: yes, you are right, I use AFNetworking get the return data. And the return data is what I want. But now the problem is the return data is just a NSData type object. I have no idea how to use it , show it in uiwebview or any other ways.

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding this method, and return YES:

```
    - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    return YES;
}
```

Remember to set your class a UIWebViewDelegate and link your UIWebView's `.delegate` property to `self`.